# SwiftyJSON - no access to JSON data

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to parse server response produced by following code (api for rails app developed with grape)

```
  if user.persisted?
    return user.to_json
  else
    error!(user.errors.to_json, 400)
  end
```

When user submit wrong data i see following response from server:

```
{
    response = "{\"email\":[\"is invalid\"],\"password\":[\"is too short (minimum is 8 characters)\"]}";
    "response_type" = error;
}
```

I use on client side following code:

```
API.registerUser(email: emailTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text, password_confirmation: passwordConfirmationTextField.text) {
    (data, error, statusCode) in

    var errorMessage: String

    if (data == nil && statusCode == nil) {
        errorMessage = "Server error. Please try again later"
    } else if (statusCode == 400) {
        var errors = JSON(data!)["response"]

        errorMessage = "Registration error: \n"

        // Display error notice with details

        errorMessage = errorMessage + errors.stringValue

        }

        NSLog(errorMessage)
}
```

In this code errors variable contains **"{\"email\":[\"is invalid\"],\"password\":[\"is too short (minimum is 8 characters)\"]}"** but i cannot use errors["email"] - it contains no data. How can i loop thru errors and access all data?

Comment: Parse the JSON, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was on a server side, because it generated escaped json. I've fixed it with following

```
error!(user.errors, 400)
```

It was my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to parse the response key in order to read it as a dictionary. It also looks like you might have to unescape the response before you parse it unless your parser takes care of that for you.